# Can a \mathlig be changed later in the document?

Tags: macros

This is with regard to the `\mathlig` command provided by the `semantic` package.

Is it possible to change what a symbol combination maps to later in the document? For example, is it possible to first use `\mathlig{|-}{\vdash}`, and later redefine it to include a subscript, e.g., `\mathlig{|-}{\vdash_\tau}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try it? It seems to just work as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ligature]{semantic}

\begin{document}
\mathlig{|-}{\vdash}

First definition: $|-$

\mathlig{|-}{\vdash_\tau}
Second definition: $|-$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess I rushed to ask before trying. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, you should add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem to your question. In this case, you'd have found that it works. In other cases, it really helps potential answerers out a lot to see what you've tried.

Comment: In a large document, this gives me a "tex capacity exceeded" error. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure. I recommend asking a new question with a MWE demonstrating the problem. You'll get more visibility than asking in a comment.