# tex capacity exceeded when re-defining a \mathlig (semantic package)

Tags: macros

As per [Can a \mathlig be changed later in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376415/can-a-mathlig-be-changed-later-in-the-document), this example is possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ligature]{semantic}

\begin{document}
\mathlig{|-}{\vdash}

First definition: $|-$

\mathlig{|-}{\vdash_\tau}
Second definition: $|-$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, when I try it in a larger document, I get this error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\do #1#2#3->\mathcode `#1
                         ="8000
```

Apologies for being unable to provide a minimal working example, I am not certain how big the document needs to be to get the error. Any ideas about what could be causing this, and where to start looking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using the `turnstile` package?

Comment: Why do you think this is the cause of the error? You might strike lucky, but generally, nobody is going to be able to help you resolve an error without code to reproduce it.

Comment: I understand your concern, but I am not sure how to be more specific. The problem literally disappears if I do not re-define the same \mathlig later in the document.

Comment: Start with a copy of your document and remove stuff until you can't remove anything else without removing the error. Then you have your MWE.